# Two-column figure shows up underneath text

Tags: floats, two-column

I'm trying to add this two-column image a the top of this page; however, it shows up underneath the text.

```
    \begin{figure*}[htb!]
    \label{fig:2}
    \includegraphics[trim=0cm 3.5in 0cm 3.5in,clip=true, width=6in]{2}
    \caption{asdfasdf}
    \end{figure*}
```

Without the [!] the image goes to the next page, and with [H] and `\usepackage{float}` the image doesn't appear at all. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Here is the rest of the code:

```
\documentclass[aps,twocolumn,secnumarabic,balancelastpage,amsmath,amssymb,nofootinbib]{revtex4}



\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{chapterbib}    % allows a bibliography for each chapter (each labguide has it's own)
\usepackage{color}         % produces boxes or entire pages with colored backgrounds
\usepackage{graphics}      % standard graphics specifications
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}      % alternative graphics specifications
\usepackage{longtable}     % helps with long table options
\usepackage{epsf}          % old package handles encapsulated post script issues
\usepackage{bm}            % special 'bold-math' package
\usepackage{verbatim}           % for comment environment
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}  % this package should be added after all others
                                        

\begin{document}

Blah Blah Text

\begin{figure*}[htb]
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 4.4in 0cm 4.4in,clip=true, width=6in]{ringdown_freqscan}
\caption{Left:Blah Blah}
\label{fig:rdfs}
\end{figure*}

MORE TEXT

\par

Designed by UF researchers, the suck stick is inserted into the top 
of the dewar and contains a port at its top to pump out its inside. 
At the 

\begin{figure*}[htb!]
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 3.5in 0cm 3.5in,clip=true, width=6in]{damp_freq}
\caption{asdfasdf}
\label{fig:damp_freq}
\end{figure*}
very base of the suck stick is a capillary intended to allow a very
specific amount of the contents of the dewar into the cryostat where


MORE TEXT

\end{document}
```

The second figure is sandwiched in the middle of the sentence because that is the point at which a new page begins.

[image: two-column image underneath text]

I should add that I was able to do this with the first image as seen here:
[image: correct way]

Attached are the two images (I am using pdfs in the actual code but have linked them as pngs here since SE can't link pdfs.)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWzP3.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax8h3.png

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, @Max Seixas. Please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: @FHZ I went ahead and added the rest of the code to my question, thank you!

Comment: We can't test your code because we don't have those images, so it's hard to know for sure, but I would guess this is caused by the `trim=...` options to `\includegraphics`. Remove those or at least drastically reduce the measurements given for them.

Comment: @frabjous I'm still pretty stuck on this but went ahead and included links to the images above. As stated, I am using pdfs in my file so converting them to a pdf first might be helpful. thank you!

Comment: After playing around with it a little more I realized you were completely right, the trim function didn't need any values!

Comment: the trim is causing the over-print, and `figure*` does not accept h or b so `[htb!]`  is the same as `[!t]` so mainly just preventing a float page `p`, probably best not to use the option at all so the default setting is used.

Comment: figure* **always** goes to the next page.  All you can to is move it earlier in the text (immediately after the previous float).

Comment: We still can't test it with just one of the two images. Do the pngs have the same margins as the pdfs? Post a link to *both* images, and in your sample, use something like the `lipsum` or `blindtext` packages to add dummy text to recreate the exact scenario you're facing.